# MYSQL issue howto count result in master table not including all rows from a Detail table "labels" used in a join

Tags: mysql, distinct

To simplify the question I am only using a few field in my test table example

Master db

```
Id  Description type  cost
'1', 'Test1', '2', '100'
'2', 'Test2', '2', '100'
'3', 'Test3', '3', '100'
'4', 'Test4', '4', '100'
```

Labels db

```
 ID     Name     Masterid
'1', 'Label1', '1'
'2', 'Label1', '2'
'3', 'Label2', '1'
'4', 'Label3', '1'
```

I would like to count all ID's and make summary for the cost field for all records in master containing label1 and label2 from labels

My Query

```
Select  count(Distinct m.id) as andtall , sum(m.cost) as cost
from
 master m

  join labels l ON  l.Masterid=m.id and l.name in ('Label1','Label2')
```

Since I am using Distinct in count that result will be correct, but Cost is wrong it's containg 3 records not 2.

'2', '300'   I would like it to return 200 since only 2 records from master table should be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT  
  count( m.id ) as andtall,
  sum( m.cost ) as cost
FROM
 master m
 JOIN ( 
    SELECT 
      Masterid
    FROM 
      labels l 
    WHERE
      l.name in ('Label1', 'Label2') 
    GROUP BY master_id ) l ON l.Masterid = m.id
```